# Viability of using the "tv_nsec" nanosecond component returned by "timespec_get()" on Linux as random number generator in C?

Tags: c, random, timespec

With the following simple code snippet:

```
struct timespec ts;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
    printf("%ld, ", ts.tv_nsec % 100);
}
```

I get output like this:

`58, 1, 74, 49, 5, 59, 89, 20, 52, 86, 17, 48, 79, 10, 41, 73, 3, 40, 72, 3, 36, 67, 98, 30, 61, 92, 24, 55, 86, 17, 49, 82, 14, 45, 76, 7, 40, 72, 3, 36, 71, 2, 35, 66, 97, 28, 66, 97, 28, 60, 90, 22, 52, 83, 15, 46, 77, 7, 41, 72, 3, 36, 67, 0, 44, 17, 82, 13, 45, 77, 8, 59, 90, 22, 54, 85, 17, 48, 80, 12, 43, 75, 6, 57, 89, 20, 52, 84, 15, 47, 79, 14, 50, 82, 16, 47, 79, 11, 43, 74,`

I haven't studied the statistical distribution of the numbers and my searches have turned up blank, but the output does at first glance look similar to output of `rand()` or `random()`. Has anyone studied this or is able to express an opinion - could `timespec_get()` be used as random number generator? Would it be pseudo random or not? Why?

Comment: Viability? Most probably *none*.

Comment: I think it is already used on the kernel, but you know: on two different servers (or maybe router, with low load, few programs), you may get the same sequence.

Comment: You should really check recent development of Linux kernel and PRNG based on instruction execution jitter.

Comment: Note that with this code `printf()` is called, a sinkhole of CPU time.  Try making 10 "random" numbers in a row and then print them.

Comment: Note that on some non-Linux systems, the last three decimal digits of `tv_nsec` are always 0 — macOS is one such system.  POSIX provides `clock_getres()` which tells you about this; standard C, the author of `timespec_get()` does not provide that information.  In C11, [footnote 321](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note321) to [§7.27.2.5 The `timespec_get` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.2.5) says: _Although a struct timespec object describes times with nanosecond resolution, the available resolution is system dependent and may even be greater than 1 second._

Comment: Link to POSIX [`clock_getres()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_getres.html) function.

Comment: Using the values returned by `timespec_get()` as input to a seed generation algorithm for passing to the seed function for a PRNG is probably reasonably good — better than just a value from `time()`, for example.  You might hash the whole value obtained from `timespec_get()`, for example, and pass the hash value to `srand()` or whatever (e.g. `srand48()` if you use the POSIX [`drand48()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/drand48.html) family of PRNG functions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> could `timespec_get()` be used as random number generator?

Of course.  But that doesn't mean the output of such a RNG would have desirable or even acceptable statistical properties.

In particular, successive outputs are strongly correlated with each other.  Your example hides that, somewhat, by discarding all the most-significant decimal digits.  Additionally, the system clock is not required to have single-nanosecond resolution, though yours seems to have.  In a system that didn`t have such resolution, the least-significant digits of all results would likely be correlated, and their distribution non-uniform.

> Would it be pseudo random or not? Why?

No, actually.  The output of a PRNG is *deterministic* with respect to the runtime state of the calling program at the time of the call.  `timespec_get()`, on the other hand, depends on the program's execution context, not its own state.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have provided is almost certainly guaranteed *not* to provide (pseudo-)random numbers!

Why?

Consider running this on an efficient CPU that can dedicate 100% of its time to your code (and with nothing else of 'significant impact') going on in the OS background: each run of the `for` loop executes an *identical* instruction sequence, so the intervals between successive calls to `timespec_get` will all be *very* similar - and a list of numbers with continuously similar intervals is certainly not random.

Even a fairly cursory glance through your generated number list shows that the only time a number is **less** than its precursor is when the value "rolls over" the 100 mark (this effect will be more noticeable if you increase your modulus from `100` to, say, `500` and run the test again).

Answer (score 2):

> could timespec_get() be used as random number generator?

I tried calling `timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);` multiple times and received delta values of about 14 +/- 1 ns.  To me this implies **at best** a non-predictable-ness (random-ness) of 1 bit per call (given the variability in the delta), not the 7 to 8 bits hoped for with `timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);  ts.tv_nsec % 100`.  **At worst**, there is nearly zero bits of randomness.

`.tv_nsec` and `.tv_sec` could be used to [initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59771515/viability-of-using-the-tv-nsec-nanosecond-component-returned-by-timespec-get#comment105692602_59771515) a random engine, but as as a source, it is very weak.

> Would it be pseudo random or not? Why?

No. A [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) is deterministic.  Reading time is not deterministic enough.

Comment: If you could share the code of your experiment, it would help. I would like to see what results I would get, using Linux Debian on an AMD machine. Doing a simple loop, adding results to an array, then another loop printing the array, I get deltas of around 36, with up to about 20 variability. If doing the modulo, variability is lower, about 6.

Comment: @Theod'Or Test code not postable.  If the variability is  +/- 20 in a tight loop (no prints) and not pattenred, you are getting a 3-5 bits per call.  I am surprised that that 20 is on the order of 36.